# function does not exist in Google Sheets API

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have a function which I am trying to open ***The code seems to be trying to upload a file rather than open it*** an excel file in byte format using Google Sheets API `Google Sheets API`, using version `1.57.0.2826.`

But it gives me an error in a function in the part of the Media function, which tells me that it does not exist

I'm trying this code but it gives me **the error *-error message-***

```
var request = servicio.Spreadsheets.Create(new Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Spreadsheet());
request.Media = new Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload.MediaUpload(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
request.Fields = "spreadsheetId";
var response = request.Execute();
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error? And whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.